# Wrap a Div-layout for a navigation bar

Tags: navigation, html

I have a navigation bar in which the 8 main links for the site are in 100px wide  tags.

This is fine on a wide screen. They appear as one uniform bar.

When the page is viewed on a mobile device, I want my mobile CSS to make them stack, so that on a 490px screen, there would be two rows of four  "bottons". If possible, I would like to do this while using a single class for the s.

A little help?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  ...
}
```

More instructions on using media queries: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: I must be missing something, Jure C.

Comment: I must be missing something, Jure C. I can get it to understand to use the mobile css for the narrower screen. But I can't get the <div> boxes/buttons to stack. Of the dozen ways I've tried it they keep either overlapping on each other or so that each gets its own line. I can't get them to wrap the way text would.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to get this to work would be to code something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="height:auto;width:100%">
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 1</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 2</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 3</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 4</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">testtoo</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 6</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 7</a></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;"><a href="#">test me 8</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can try to resize your screen and will stack as you want.

One key here is to use the float:left of the inner divs, which will keep them on the same level.

The size of the bar will be the width of the screen, so you can play with that percentage and other values to get your desired output.

**fixed where the size was set. has to be in the , not the

you can do all this using CSS classes instead, it is probably much easier